# How do I extract documents from a mongoDB collection using ejs such that each appears once on browser?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes, ejs

I want someone to, please, help me to get over this hurdle. I'm trying to extract some documents that have the same properties from `mongoDB`. I'm using `ejs` template and mongoose.
Everything is working properly except that each of the documents appears more than once on the browser but I want each to appear once and in a sequential order.
I have the following code:
`indexSchema:`

```
const indexSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    quote: String,
    image:  String,
    imageCaption: String,
    author: String,
    qualification: String,
    body: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});
const Index =  mongoose.model('Index', indexSchema)
module.exports = Index;
```

Index route:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    await Index.find((err, index) => {
         if (err){
              console.log("Sorry, posts not found successfully");
              console.log(err);
          } else{
             
          console.log("Collections received successfully!")
          res.render("index", {index:index});
```

index.ejs:

```
<%- include ('partials/header') %>
    <div class="container">
      <% index.forEach(index => { %>
        <img src="<%= index.image %>" class="img-fluid mt-0.5" alt="Responsive image">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mt-1">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div>
                  <h3><%= index.title %></h3>
                  <h5><%= index.subtitle %>.</h5><i><%= index.quote %></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <h3 class="mb-4">Featured Posts</h3>
        <a href="posts/" class="btn btn-outline-success">View All Posts</a>
         <div class="card mt-4">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title"><%= index.title %></h4>
                  <div class="card-subtitle text-muted mb-2">
                      <%= index.createdAt.toLocaleDateString(); %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-text mb-4">
                      <%= index.body %>
                  </div> 
                  <div>
                    <a href="/posts/<%= index._id %>" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read more<i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    <% }) %>
</div>
<%- include ('partials/footer') %>
```

From the index route, it's clear that I'm using the `find()` function. I know that this function brings back all the documents in the collection.
Since each document has a title, subtitle, author etc, it's difficult for me to make sure that each appears once on the browser using `forEach` loop.
The only means I know that would have rectified the issue for me is by targeting the id since each document has a unique id. But it seems I'm messing up everything because I do not know how to get this work in my HTML template since `findById()` appears to be incompatible with `forEach()`. Removing
`forEach()` from `ejs` also prevents all the images in the database from appearing on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by using mongoose nexted schema I was able to achieve the same result I wanted. Though this is definitely not the best approach, I was able to use it to move to the next level until I gain more experience with mongoose and ejs